# What version of CentOS is equivalent to Red Hat 9.x?

Tags: centos, rhel

I want to use CentOS. I was used to Red Hat 9.x but now I'd like to use CentOS.
But I don't know what CentOS version is equivalent to Red Hat 9.x?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Red Hat Linux 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux) was released in 2003, and discontinued in 2004. There is no direct CentOS equivalent; CentOS 2, the first release, was based on [Red Hat Enterprise Linux 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux), and is the closest release to Red Hat Linux 9 chronologically.

All these versions are over a decade old though, so you'd be better off using the latest release of CentOS, or even Red Hat Enterprise Linux which is now available free in the [developer subscription](http://developers.redhat.com/).

Comment: Just a quick warning for readers, this is specifically about Red Hat Linux - RHL, not Red Hat Enterprise Linux - RHEL, which is much more recent (latest is 9.3)